# Открыть WinApi макет

Tags: winapi, windows, visual-studio, c++

Очень давно не программировал в WinApi, но помню, что раньше когда создавал проект на WinAPi в VS, то появлялся макет окна, на которое можно было перетаскивать контролы(ну или может, я что-то для этого делал). Сейчас создал с++ WinApi проект, но не какого макета окна не открылось, только окно с С++ кодом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как открыть макет? (Понимаю, что вопрос глуповатый, но у меня похоже заскок какой то.)

Answer (score 2):

Нужно в файле ресурсов (*.rc) вашего проекта создать ресурс Dialog, и тогда появиться макет окна.

Comment: Странно, а я вроде точно помню, что я раньше этого файла не редактировал, а макет окна всё равно создавался... В ранних версиях VS, он что ли автоматически создавался? Или я чего-то путаю?

Comment: Вы тогда делали приложение на основе диалога, а теперь - на основе окна, которое создаётся кодом.

Comment: Тогда ещё один туповатый вопрос как создать прилоежние не основе диалога?

Comment: Как я описал, код окна удаляется, и прописать код (DialogProc, DialogBox) для диалога.

Comment: Понял, Спасибо.